# Shapefile import error: `Warning: Invalid latitude 116.45`

Tags: gis, shapefile, sumo

I use `netconvert` to import a shapefile like this:

```sh
netconvert --shapefile-prefix ./data/clip \
    --shapefile.street-id id \
    --shapefile.from-id SOURCE \
    --shapefile.to-id TARGET \
    --shapefile.use-defaults-on-failure
```

But it tells me that:

```sh
Warning: Invalid latitude 116.45
Warning: Invalid latitude 116.45
Warning: Invalid latitude 116.45
...
```

However, the shapefile shows correctly in `QGIS` and `GeoPandas`. It seems that the `netconvert` mixed the longtitude and the latitude. What can I do to modify the field of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use option --shapefile.traditional-axis-mapping